# Using Older Require Module With Rollup

Tags: hmac, svelte, rollupjs

I thought the commonjs plugin would let you use older modules, but I can't get rollup to work with https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-hmac.  It's an older module so as far as I know I need to use:

`const createHmac = require("create-hmac");`

I can't use an import. Is there any way to use this with rollup, or am I out of luck? I'm using the standard Svelte rollup template and  have tried using namedExports, dynamicRequireTargets, different Resolve settings, etc. If anyone who actually knows rollup could help me out it would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `import` actually, that's what `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` is for. It lets you `import` modules that export using `require`.

```js
import createHmac from 'create-hmac'
```

But that is all this module does. Not enough for you. Rollup won't resolve `node_modules` etc. by itself. This is not standard ES module resolution, it's Node specific resolution. So, for that, you also need `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`.

Still not enough. I've tried the `create-hmac` package. It requires things that are present in a Node environment but not in the browser (things like streams...). As far as I know, Webpack automatically polyfills that, but not Rollup. So you also need a plugin for that. I tried `rollup-plugin-node-builtins`. Seems to work.

So, in the end, your Rollup config should look something like this:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins'

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // polyfills Node builtins in the browser
    builtins(),

    // Node resolution mechanism (node_modules)
    resolve({
      // this tells to use the 'browser' field of the packages you install
      // when they provide it (the package you've linked does)
      browser: true,
    }),

    // to allow import of module using require
    commonjs(),
  ]
}
```